# Can modulo (%s) be placed in string when first creating a variable and then used later on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, modulo

I'm quite new to python, so forgive me if this is a silly question. I know how to use the modulo in strings in this fashion

```
Me = "I'm %s and I like to %s" % ('Mike', 'code')
```

However, through my searching I haven't found an answer to whether or not it's possible to hardcode modulos into a string, then take advantage of it later.

Example:

```
REPO_MENU = {'Issues':Api.github/repo/%s/branch/%s/issues,
         'Pull Requests':'Api.github/repo/%s/branch/%s/pull_requests',
         'Commits':'Api.github/repo/%s/branch/%s/commits'
         '<FILTER>: Branch':'Api.github/repo/%s/branch/%s'
        }

for key, value in REPO_MENU.items():
    Print value % ('Beta', 'master')
```

Will that format work? Is it good practice to use this method? I feel it could be beneficial in a lot of situations.

Comment: That's not a modulo operator. It''s a format string. Modulo means the remainder of an integer division operation (e.g., 10 modulo 7 = 3) ; it has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: In addition to the answer by @KenWhite , if you're using the 3.x interpreter it's standard to use the `str.format()` method. It is also more flexible so you don't have to provide the format specifier. Oh and I think `'Mike, code'` should have been `'Mike', 'code'`

Comment: If you are using Python 3.6 (if you can, you SHOULD!), don't use `.format` OR `%`. Instead, [use fstrings](http://tomatohater.com/2013/08/30/python-performance-string-formatting/).

Comment: @KenWhite. I have often seen that operator called modulo even when it is used for other things, like string formatting.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: So? I can call a cow a pig all I want, but that doesn't change the fact that it won't produce bacon. It's not a modulo operator in the  context used. Modulo refers to a mathematical operation, and strings don't do math.

Comment: Sorry for my misuse of the word, as @KenWhite suggested many of the sources I've seen simply refer to it as a modulo for simplicity sake and until now I was never corrected. Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: @RickTeachey thanks for the advice. The reason I'd like to work with either `.format` or `%` is because 1) To me it's more readable at the moment (still learning) and 2) It would allow for backwards compatibility for environments that are unable to use 3.x.

Comment: @DarrelHolt thanks for the heads-up as I wasn't sure which is looked at as the standard. And you are correct, thanks for catching that typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work. You can also use the **format** function, which works well. For example:

```
menu1 = {'start':'hello_{0}_{1}',
        'end':'goodbye_{0}_{1}'}

menu2 = {'start':'hello_%s_%s',
        'end':'goodbye_%s_%s'}

for key, value in menu1.items():
    print value.format('john','smith')

for key, value in menu2.items():
    print value %('john','smith')
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming and +1 for providing **both** examples. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is an operator like any other; when its left-hand operand is a string, it attempts to replace various placeholders with values from its right-hand operand. It doesn't matter if the left-hand operand is a string literal or a more complex expression, as long as it evaluates to a string.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have noted, you can definitely perform the string-modulo operation multiple times on the same string. However, if you are using Python 3.6 (and if you can, you definitely SHOULD!), I suggest that you [use fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) rather than the string-modulo or `.format`. They are [faster](http://tomatohater.com/2013/08/30/python-performance-string-formatting/), easier to read, and very convenient:

> A formatted string literal or f-string is a string literal that is prefixed with 'f' or 'F'. These strings may contain replacement fields, which are expressions delimited by curly braces {}. While other string literals always have a constant value, formatted strings are really expressions evaluated at run time.

So the f-string is also portable, just like the other formatting options.

E.g.:

```
>>> value = f'A {flower.lower()} by any name would smell as sweet.'
>>> flower = 'ROSE'
>>> print(value)
A rose by any name would smell as sweet.
>>> flower = 'Petunia'
>>> print(value)
A petunia by any name would smell as sweet.
>>> flower = 'Ferrari'
>>> print(value)
A ferrari by any name would smell as sweet.
```

You can add this at the top of any module using the f-string as a helpful alert for other users (or future-you):

```
try: 
    eval(f'')
except SyntaxError:
    print('Python 3.6+ required.')`.
    raise
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and helpful links. I will likely revisit fstrings in the future when I'm a bit more seasoned, but for now I'd like to focus on methods that provide more readability for myself in order to build my understanding.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder Added a helpful hint to the end.